# Javascript regexp pattern to match special numeric data

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

I need a regexp pattern in a JavaScript code to recognize the following texts

```
123
1.23
1.23e4
1.23d4
123_txt
1.23_txt
1.23e4_txt
```

The JavaScript code read these data from a file and should math using the rexexp pattern

What is the simple regexp pattern to match above data?

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, and we can help you with debugging.

Comment: see this
[+-]?[0-9][0-9_]*\.[0-9de+-]*

It does not work for all cases I said above!

Comment: You should add your regex to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `[+-]?[0-9][0-9_]*\.[0-9de+-]*` does not match `123` and `123_txt` because these values are not containing a dot `\.` which is not optional in your regex.

You could make the dot optional `\.?` but then you would have to account for the underscore `_` in the last two examples and the missing `txt` which is not part of the regex.

What you could do is update your regex to match one or more digits from the beginning of the string `^[0-9]+` and make the 2 patterns like `.23e4` and `_txt` after the digits optional.

Your examples do not contain a leading `+` or `-` so you might leave out `[+-]?` from the beginning. *(You can always add it)*

For your example values you could try:

[`^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+[de]?[0-9+])?(?:_txt)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/zC8uH0/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[0-9]+` Match one or more digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\.[0-9]+[de]?[0-9+]` Match a dot, one or more digits, optional `d` or `e` and then one or more digits.
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `(?:_txt)?` Optional non capturing group which matches `_txt`
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line